# Set specific layout for every other item inside collectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, modulus

I have a collectionView with a custom cell. I want to layout the imageView inside my cell with a specific layout but it's laying it out incorrectly.

[image]

The 1st and 3rd rows have the correct layout but the 2nd row layout is incorrect. The correct layout should be every image that's in the middle should be lower then the other two on either end.

The problem is inside the CollectionViewCell I'm using the modulus to set every odd cell lower then every even cell but since the 2nd row (or in every odd row) the modulus of the middle cell will always be even the layout is laying it out correctly but its not giving me what I want.

**How can I get the layout to look like the below image?**

[image]

Code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(15, 0, 5, 0)
    layout.scrollDirection = .vertical

    collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    // collectionView datasource, delegate, and cell registration set
    view.addSubview(collectionView)

    collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
    collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    collectionView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
    collectionView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 9
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! CustomCell

    cell.item = indexPath.item
 }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let width = (view.frame.width - 25) / 3
    return CGSize(width: width, height: width)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 25
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 5
}
```

Here's the code inside the CollectionViewCell I'm using to set the layout:

```
class CustomCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    var item: Int = 0 {
        didSet {
             setLayout()
        }
    }

    func setLayout() {
        addSubview(imageView)

        imageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        imageView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor).isActive = true

        if item % 2 == 0 {

            imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
            imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true

        } else {

            imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
            imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you want to check `if (item + 1) % 3 == 2` then move the cell down. Here is the edited code:

```
   if (item + 1) % 3 == 2 {
        imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true

    } else {

        imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
        imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    }
```

Comment: It didn’t work. It pushed every 3rd cell up. The first two cells in every row is on the same level but the 3rd cell is higher

Answer (score 0):

lets see.... the items you want to move are 2 ,5, and 8... +3

so... try....

```
if item == 2 {
    imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true

} 
if (item - 2 ) % 3 == 0{
imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
 } else {
    imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
}
```

// do you see where I'm going? the exception to your rule is 2. you need every 2 + 3(n) cell to be adjusted.

```
// so if item = 2; process code
// if item = 5: minus it by 2; item = 3 which % 3 == 0
// if item = 8: minus it by 2; item = 6 which % 3 == 0

// and so on. 
// hope you understand now, I'm not very good at explaining,
```

Comment: I’ll read through your answer in the morning. It’s 11:30 pm over here. Thanks, even though I found the accepted answer every little bit helps :)

Comment: Nevermind! my answer is the same as Leo Fengs (except his is easier)! I didn't refresh my browser so it didn't show the correct answer. His uses addition while mine uses subtraction :) I hope after both our explanations you see why it was off though:)